# enet() works but not when run via caret::train()

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm trying to run an elastic net.  Starting with LASSO and going from there.  I can get it to run directly but it fails when I try to run the same parameters using `train` in the `caret` package.  I'd like to get `train` working so that I can use it to evaluate model parameters.

```
# Works
test <- enet( x=x, y=y, lambda=0, trace=TRUE, normalize=FALSE, intercept=FALSE )
# Doesn't
enetGrid <- data.frame(.lambda=0,.fraction=c(.01,.001,.0005,.0001))
ctrl <- trainControl( method="repeatedcv", repeats=5 )
> test2 <- train( x, y, method="enet", tuneGrid=enetGrid, trControl=ctrl, preProc=NULL )
  fraction lambda RMSE Rsquared RMSESD RsquaredSD
1    1e-04      0  NaN      NaN     NA         NA
2    5e-04      0  NaN      NaN     NA         NA
3    1e-03      0  NaN      NaN     NA         NA
4    1e-02      0  NaN      NaN     NA         NA
Error in train.default(x, y, method = "enet", tuneGrid = enetGrid, trControl = ctrl,  : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
...
50: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Fold10.Rep5: lambda=0, fraction=0.01 Error in enet(as.matrix(trainX), trainY, lambda = lmbda) : 
  Some of the columns of x have zero variance
```

Note that any collinearity in the above example is just a result of subsetting down for a reproducible example (1,000 rows vs. 208,000 in the real dataset).

I've checked the full dataset in various ways, including `findLinearCombos`.  Note that a few hundred of the variables are dummied out from clinical diagnoses and thus are binary with a low proportion of 1's.

How do I get `train(...,method="enet") to run using the exact same settings as`enet()`?

**Data for reproducibility, sesionInfo, etc.**

Sample data `x` and `y` are [available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ead9ugoidqslfjo/xy.Rdata).

Results of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C          
 [8] LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
 [1] parallel  splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_0.2.3        elasticnet_1.1      fscaret_0.8.5.3     gsubfn_0.6-5        proto_0.3-10        lars_1.2            caret_5.17-7       
 [8] foreach_1.4.1       cluster_1.14.4      lubridate_1.3.0     HH_2.3-37           reshape_0.8.4       latticeExtra_0.6-24 leaps_2.9          
[15] multcomp_1.2-18     perturb_2.05        Zelig_4.2-0         sandwich_2.2-10     zoo_1.7-10          survey_3.29-5       Hmisc_3.12-2       
[22] survival_2.37-4     lme4_0.999999-2     bayesm_2.2-5        stargazer_4.0       pscl_1.04.4         vcd_1.2-13          colorspace_1.2-2   
[29] mvtnorm_0.9-9995    car_2.0-18          nnet_7.3-7          gdata_2.13.2        gtools_3.0.0        spBayes_0.3-7       Formula_1.1-1      
[36] magic_1.5-4         abind_1.4-0         MapGAM_0.6-2        gam_1.08            fields_6.7.6        maps_2.3-2          spam_0.29-3        
[43] FNN_1.0             spatstat_1.31-3     mgcv_1.7-24         rgeos_0.2-19        RArcInfo_0.4-12     automap_1.0-12      gstat_1.0-16       
[50] SDMTools_1.1-13     rgdal_0.8-10        spdep_0.5-60        coda_0.16-1         deldir_0.0-22       maptools_0.8-25     nlme_3.1-110       
[57] MASS_7.3-27         Matrix_1.0-12       lattice_0.20-15     boot_1.3-9          data.table_1.8.8    xtable_1.7-1        RCurl_1.95-4.1     
[64] bitops_1.0-5        RColorBrewer_1.0-5  testthat_0.7.1      codetools_0.2-8     devtools_1.3        stringr_0.6.2       foreign_0.8-54     
[71] ggplot2_0.9.3.1     sp_1.0-11           taRifx_1.0.5        reshape2_1.2.2      plyr_1.8            functional_0.4      R.utils_1.25.2     
[78] R.oo_1.13.9         R.methodsS3_1.4.4  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] LearnBayes_2.12  compiler_3.0.1   dichromat_2.0-0  digest_0.6.3     evaluate_0.4.4   gtable_0.1.2     httr_0.2         intervals_0.14.0 iterators_1.0.6 
[10] labeling_0.2     memoise_0.1      munsell_0.4.2    rpart_4.1-1      spacetime_1.0-5  stats4_3.0.1     tcltk_3.0.1      tools_3.0.1      whisker_0.3-2   
[19] xts_0.9-5
```

**Update**

Run on a 15% sample of the dataset:

```
Warning in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  model fit failed for Fold10.Rep1: lambda=0, fraction=0.005
... (more of the same warning messages) ...
Warning in nominalTrainWorkflow(dat = trainData, info = trainInfo, method = met\
hod,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
Error in if (lambda > 0) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: train ... train.default -> system.time -> createModel -> enet
```

There are 806 columns of the X matrix, 801 of them dummies.  Many of these dummies are extremely sparse (1-3 observations out of 25k or so rows), others have 0.1-5% of their values as TRUE.  In total, there are 108867 TRUE's and 21mm FALSE's.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coaxing R to do what you want or using a package and not a statistical issue.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I was thinking it would be more appropriate here, but I guess not.  Flagged for migration to SO.

Comment: Did you get any error message running `train()` ?

Comment: If the main problem is collinearity, one of possible approaches is to add small (relatively to columns' standard deviations) random error to data before running `train()`

Comment: The same should work with zero variance as well

Comment: @O_Devinyak Why would `enet` work when run directly then?

Comment: @O_Devinyak Plus I don't think it had that problem when I ran it on the full dataset.  Just an artifact of having a sample dataset

Comment: It is the problem of subsampling. When the crossvalidation is running, some samples are drawn such way that some columns become constant. In whole data that is used by enet there no constant columns, so enet() goes fine. But in samples used for crossvalidation they are.

Comment: @O_Devinyak But 20% of 200k observations is still 40k observations.  If `enet` can run on 1000 observations, why can't `train` run it on a subsample?

Comment: In the example both methods are run with the same `x`. Do the really used different: `enet` on 1000 but `train` on 200k?. In any case it is good to check whether there are many duplicated values in some column. Like `sapply(x,function(column){max(table(column))}`

Comment: @O_Devinyak Noted in the question: the example dataset (`enet` and `train` both run on) has 1k observations, but the real dataset (`enet` and `train` both run on) has 208k.  Problem still occurs in real dataset, without the warnings().

Comment: I've checked the full dataset in various ways, including findLinearCombos. Note that a few hundred of the variables are dummied out from clinical diagnoses and thus are binary with a low proportion of 1's.

Comment: The given warning says that in case of 1k observations the fail is caused by sampling of nearly constant column. The cause why the whole data run fails as well is not so straightforward since there were no warnings. The ways to test that fact are 1)delete that binaries and check `train()` 2) Add random error to these columns 3) Write your own crossvalidation function with splitting that is stratified by given columns

Comment: @O_Devinyak Ok.  I'm running on the full dataset now to confirm the warning is still there, and I'll try to implement some of your suggestions and see how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: To decrease the running time you may pass `repeats=1` to `trainControl()`. Note, that you are running not five-fold crossvalidation, but 5 independent iterations of ten-fold. For testing 1 iteration is enough. I hope my suggestions will help.

Comment: @O_Devinyak Thanks.  Stopped the 5x and trying the 1x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to bring some resolution to this, I have it working now.  I dropped all columns with less than 20 `TRUE`'s (remember, this is out of almost 200k observations) as simply having insufficient information to contribute.  This wound up being about half of them.

I will have to be cautious that these sparse columns don't contribute too much bias, etc. as I move forward, but I am hoping that by using a method that does variable selection (lasso, RF, etc.) that will be less of a problem.

Thanks to @O_Devinyak for the help.